# Formula for calculating $\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I want to know the general formula for $\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n$ for some constant $r$ and how it is derived.

For example, when $r = 2$, the formula is given by:$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}n2^n = 2(m2^m - 2^m +1),$$according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+sum+of+n+2%5En).

Thanks!

Comment: @dragoncharmer Either you tag this [algebra-precalculus] or you tag it [taylor-expansion]. Those are quite mutually exclusive tags.

Comment: See also: [What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180198)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I see that one of the tags is pre-calculus, so here is a way to answer the question that does not use differentiation:

$S = r + 2r^2 +3r^3 +\dots + (m-1)r^{m-1}+mr^m $
$rS = \  \ \ \  r^2 +2r^3 +\dots + (m-2)r^{m-1}+(m-1)r^m + mr^{m+1} $

Subtracting the bottom line from the top, we get
$$(1-r)S = r+r^2 +r^3 + \dots + r^{m-1} + r^m -mr^{m+1} .$$
But using the formula for  the sum of a geometric series, we have that
$$(1-r)S = \frac{r(1-r^m)}{1-r} -mr^{m+1}.$$
Dividing by $(1-r)$, we have
$$
S=\frac{r(1-r^m)}{(1-r)^2} -\frac{mr^{m+1}}{1-r}.
$$
(Obviously, for this to hold, one needs $r \neq 1$. If $r=1$, then we are looking at 
$\sum_{n=1}^m n= \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$.)

Comment: You do not even need to know the formula for a geometric series. From your series  expression for $(1-r)S$ you could repeat your multiply and subtract steps to get $(1-r)^2S = r -(m+1)r^{m+1}+mr^{m+2}$ and thus your final result

Comment: Btw this is essentially a "discrete derivative", equivalent to differentiation for a generating function.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that your formula $\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n$ can be obtained from $\sum_{n=0}^{m}x^n$ by applying $x\frac d{dx}$ (deriving and then multiplying by $x$) and then substituting $r$ for $x$. Now for geometric series one has the well known formula
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^mx^n=\frac{x^0-x^{m+1}}{1-x}
$$
and applying  $x\frac d{dx}$ to the right hand side gives
$$
  \frac{x-(m+1)x^{m+1}+mx^{m+2}}{(1-x)^2} = x\frac{1-x^m+mx^m(x-1)}{(1-x)^2}
  =x\left(\frac{1-x^m}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{mx^m}{1-x}\right)
$$
so that your answer should be
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n=r\left(\frac{1-r^m}{(1-r)^2}-\frac{mr^m}{1-r}\right).
$$
For $r=2$ this gives $2(1+(m-1)2^m)$, in accordance with what you found.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- The Geometric series...
- Differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are familiar with the sum of an geometric progression:
$$
1+x+x^2+\dots+x^m=\frac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}.
$$
Take derivatives an multiply by $x$.

Comment: Typo: sum of Geometric progression