# How do we get the result of the summation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formula for calculating $\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn)

Can someone explain step by step how to derive the following identity?  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot 2^k = 2(n \cdot 2^n - 2^n + 1) $$

Comment: What formulas related to this one do you know?

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn)

Comment: I recall the basic ones, that we are expected to know:             sum of k = 1 to n of k is n(n+1) / 2 and geometric series formula ie. sum of n = 0 to m of a* r ^n

Comment: Isn't this a multi duplicate?

Comment: Here are two more similar questions: [How to compute the  formula $\sum  \limits_{r=1}^d r \cdot 2^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11464) and [What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180198)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know $\sum_{k=1}^n a^k=\frac{a^{n+1}-a}{a-1}$, take the derivative of both sides with respect to $a$, multiply by $a$, and set $a=2$

Comment: Since the lower index of the summation is $1$, the RHS should be $\frac{a^{n + 1} - \color{red}{a}}{a - 1}$.

Answer (score 8):

Although you got great answers, I will add another way to look at the expression you are looking for

Let us denote

$$ S = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot 2^k $$

This can be expanded as

$$ 
\begin{align*}
  S &= 2 + 2 . 2^2 + 3 . 2^3 + \cdots n 2^n\\
2S &= \hspace{8pt}+1.2^2+2.2^3 + \cdots (n-1) . 2^n+n . 2^{n+1}
\end{align*}
$$

If you notice, by multiplying by $2$ and writing under similar terms and then subtracting, we get

$$
\begin{align*}
S = n . 2^{n+1} - \left(2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^n \right) &= n .2^{n+1}-2^{n+1}+2\\
&= 2(n . 2^n-2^n+1)
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Induction is a surefire way to prove it with elementary methods. With calculus and some formulas, we can approach this problem by evaluating a derivative in two different ways, as follows:

**Quotient rule**: $$\rm \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} =\frac{n\,x^{n-1}(x-1)-(x^n-1)(1)}{(x-1)^2} \tag{1}$$

**Geometric formula**:

$$\rm \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=0+1x^0+2x^1+\cdots+n\,x^{n-1} \tag{2}$$

Equate equation $(1)$ with equation $(2)$, multiply both sides by $\rm x$ and then set $\rm x=2$.

Comment: Your last term in $(2)$ should be $nx^{n-1}$ instead