# Limit of $\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r}{2^r}$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider the sequence $u_{n}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r}{2^r}$ with $n \ge 1$.
>   Then the limit of $u_{n}$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$ is ?

I actually treated each term as an AGP and got $$u_{n}=2-\frac{1}{2^{r+1}}-\frac{n}{2^{r+1}}$$

But how to get the limit?

Comment: That formula for $u_n$ can't be right. When $n$ increases, $u_n$ ought to increase.

Comment: You actually want to find $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}rx^r$ for $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Do you know how to evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}rx^r$?

Comment: See also: [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337937) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/337937).

Comment: If you are interested also in the finite sums, there are also several posts that you could check such as: [How to compute the  formula $\sum  \limits_{r=1}^d r \cdot 2^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11464), [How do we get the result of the summation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120091) or [What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180198)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known result due to [Nicole Oresme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicole_Oresme)
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2
\end{align}
Here is the proof

Consider the function
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}
\end{align*}
The power series expansion of $f(z)$ is
\begin{align}
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n
\end{align}
Now take the derivative of $f$, which is
\begin{align*}
f'(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}
\end{align*}
Multiplying by $z$
\begin{align}
zf'(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Substituting $z=1/2$ in (1)
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\biggl(1-\frac{1}{2}\biggl)^2}=2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let me do this (a bit non-rigorously) without derivatives.

Let $S=\frac12+\frac24+\frac38+\dots+\frac{r}{2^r}+\cdots$

Then

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac12+\frac24+\frac38+\frac4{16}+\cdots
\\&=\frac12+\frac12\left(\frac22+\frac34+\frac48+\cdots\right)
\\&=\frac12+\frac12\left(\left(\frac12+\frac12\right)+\left(\frac24+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac38+\frac18\right)+\cdots\right)
\\&=\frac12+\frac12\left(\left(\frac12+\frac24+\frac38+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\right)\right)
\\&=\frac12+\frac12(S+1)
\end{align}$$

Solving gives $S=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty r a^r = a \frac{d}{da}\sum_{r=1}^\infty a^r$$

Comment: I think you should also note that it holds for $|a|<1$, not everywhere.

Comment: Yes - thanks. The hint is to get the ball rolling.