# Deriving formula for a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to derive a formula for this series? If there is, how can it be derived?

$$\sum_{R=1}^{K-1} (R\times2^R)$$

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: Or perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120091/how-do-we-get-the-result-of-the-summation-sum-limits-k-1n-k-cdot-2k and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-limits-r-1d-r-cdot-2r?

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

> $$x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^Nnx^n$$