# Derive the sum of $\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

For the series

> $$1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + ... + nx^{n-1}+... $$

and $x \ne 1, |x| < 1$.

I need to find partial sums and finally, the sum $S_n$ of series.
Here is what I've tried:

1. We can take a series $S_2 = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ...$ so that
   $\frac{d(S_2)}{dx} = S_1$ (source series).
2. For the $|x| < 1$ the sum of $S_2$ (here is geometric progression): $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}$
3. $S_1 = \frac{d(S_2)}{dx} = \frac{d(\frac{1}{1-x})}{dx} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

But this answer is incorrect. Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: This is correct for the sum to $\infty$ but you need to take the derivative of $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ for the partial sum.

Comment: Minor notional detail: derivatives are written $\frac{d}{dx}$ not $\frac{d}{d}$.

Comment: DMcMor, fixed, thank you

Comment: The summation in the title is incorrect, the index is $i$, not $n$.

Comment: fixed as well...

Comment: Also note that $|x|<1\implies x\ne1$.

Comment: Yes, I do understand this.

Comment: Hem, so it is redundant to specify $x\ne1,|x|<1$.

Comment: There are *many* similar questions on this site already. Here are a few, for a start: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180198/what-is-the-sum-of-sum-limits-i-1nipi, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn

Comment: One more remark. You define $S_n$ as a sum of $n$ terms $ix^i$, then work with $S_1$ and $S_2$, which are defined differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p_n(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n x^i$$ is a polynomial, which you can differentiate term-wise, giving the polynomial

$$p'_n(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}.$$

At the same time, $p(x)$ is the sum of terms of a geometric series, and for $x\ne1$,

$$p_n(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}-1.$$

Then, for all $x\ne1$,

$$p'_n(x)=\frac{(n+1)x^n}{x-1}-\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}.$$

---

The limit exists for all $|x|<1$, and

$$p'_\infty(x)=\dfrac1{(x-1)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I liked your way of solving, but as I've mentioned in my question, the answer $S_n = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ is incorrect...

Comment: @Alex: do you see that in my answer ?

Comment: thank you, I really misunderstood your answer :) it is correct!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a good notion!

Integrating the partial sum

$$1+2x+\cdots nx^{n-1}$$ gives you $$C+x+x^2+\cdots x^n,$$ for some constant $C,$ which is $$C-1+\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$ Then, taking the derivative using the quotient rule gets you $$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{-(n+1)(1-x)x^n+1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2} &=& \frac{-(n+1)x^n+(n+2)x^{n+1}+1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}\\ &=& \frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(1-x)^2}\end{eqnarray}$$ for your partial sum's closed form.

You've correctly found the closed form of the limit of the partial sums.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I probably misunderstand what does "closed form" mean. 
I've tried your answer, but this is incorrect as well...

Comment: A "closed form" of a sum is one that doesn't use the $\Sigma.$ For example, the closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$ is $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ so long as $x\ne 1.$ The closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ whenever $|x|<1.$ The answer is correct. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+(k%2B1)*x%5Ek+from+k%3D0+to+n) for verification.

Comment: Ah! I missed that the indices were supposed to range from $0$ to $n-1,$ rather than from $0$ to $n.$ I will adjust my answer accordingly now.