# Closed for expression for geometric and arithmetico-geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can you help me prove this two sigmas:

$$\sum_{k=2}^n 2^{1-k} = 2^{-n}(2^n - 2) $$

and this

$$\sum_{k=2}^n k2^{1-k} = 3-2^{1-n}(n+2) $$

Is there any common way to solve this kind of tasks? Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Multiply the first one by $1-2^{-1}$ and the second by $1-1+2^{-2}$, but don't cancel anything until you have first distributed the multiplication.

Comment: First one: geometric sum. Second one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn (and many other similar questions on this site).