# Finding $T_{200}$ of given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a certain series, the $n$th term, $T_n=4T_{n-1} + n – 1$. If $T_1$ = 4, then find the value of $T_{200}$.

I tried the following:

$T_n-T_{n-1}=3T_{n-1} + n – 1$

$T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}=3T_{n-2} + n – 2$

$T_{n-2}-T_{n-3}=3T_{n-3} + n – 3$

Then I proceeded to calculate the difference of the first $2$ and the last $2$ to get:

$$T_n-3T_{n-1}+3T_{n-2}-T_{n-3}=3(T_{n-1} -T_{n-3})$$

Well $\dots$ basically I didn't reach anywhere (neither LHS nor RHS is in friendly form). Then I also tried taking $n^{th}$ order differences and then I got a GP at $3^{rd}$ order difference but still didn't know what to do from there (I'm only familiar with APs of $n^{th}$ order difference).

How to solve this problem? Please help.

Answer (and its format):

> $$\frac {10(4^{200})-601}9$$

### Edit:

Kindly suggest such that even if the question is tweaked a bit, I may be able to solve that too. For example:
$$T_n=3T_{n-1} + n – 1\text { and } T_1 = 3 \text { then } T_{100}=?$$

Comment: You can prove by induction that $T_n = \frac{10(4^n) - 3n - 1}{9}.$

Comment: Let $u_n=9T_n+3n+1$ and show that  $u_n=4u_{n-1}$

Comment: Writing an answer, request you to wait. Actually, hang on, it'll be a  duplicate answer, hence not required.

Comment: @Fikilis I don't know the RHS. I need to find it. The answer I only mentioned so that the format is intact otherwise I might not have mentioned.

Comment: @Lozenges how do I know how to let $u_n$ such a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to transform the original sequence $\{T_n\}$ to a geometric sequence by absorbing the term $n - 1$ into the transformed sequence. To this end, we are trying to rewrite the original recurrence relation as
\begin{equation*}
T_n + an + b = 4(T_{n - 1} + a(n - 1) + b),
\end{equation*}
where $a$ and $b$ are to be determined by
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
4an - an = n \\[1em]
4b - 4a - b = -1
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, $a = 1/3, b = (4a - 1)/3 = 1/9$.  Hence
\begin{align*}
T_n + \frac{1}{3}n + \frac{1}{9} = \left(T_1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9}\right)4^{n - 1}.  
\end{align*}

$T_{200}$ then follows easily.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. From the first 2 sentences it seems you have also established that $a_n=a_{n-1}$. Is there a typing error or am I not getting something?

Comment: @InanimateBeing What has been established is $a_n = 4a_{n - 1} - 1$ -- what makes you think that $a_n = a_{n - 1}$ was established??? By the way, your edited new question is trivial if you really understand the above process.

Comment: I know edit is trivial for you. I said above statement because $T_n + kn = 4(T_n + kn) - 1$
 Here you have taken $(T_n + kn)$ on the LHS as $a_n$ and $(T_n + kn)$ on the RHS as $a_{n-1}$. Please clear where I'm wrong.

Comment: I, though apparent, hesitated to call it a typo as once you correct that then other doubts arise. Now $a_{n-1}$ wouldn't be equal to $T_{n-1}+n/3$. Could you please proofread the whole and check if it matches the answer. If have no problem on continuing on my own and did it first time too.

Comment: @InanimateBeing My apology.  Edited the answer.

Comment: How did we know that we need to transform the original sequence to a geometric sequence (and that other terms will be absorbed)?

Comment: @InanimateBeing Let $c_n = T_n + n/3 + 1/9$, then the answer gives you $c_n = 4c_{n - 1}$, which is a geometric sequence, which [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Elementary_properties) its $n$-th term is $c_n = c_1 4^{n - 1}$.

Comment: Finally, in your final equation how were you directly able to write/bring T1, I'm unable to get the logic? (One can look at it as going from $c_2$ to $c_{200}$ but this thought process consumes a lot of time, so how were you able to skip this train of thought?)

Comment: As I already explained, can't you see $c_1 = T_1 + 1/3 + 1/9$, by the notation I used in last comment? Honestly it is a fair straightforward substitution, why it looks so burdernsome to you?

Answer (score 3):

By the question, we know $T_n+\frac{n}{3}+\frac{1}{9}=4(T_{n-1}+\frac{n-1}{3}+\frac{1}{9})$, so
$T_{200}+\frac{200}{3}+\frac{1}{9}=4^{199}(t_1+0+\frac{1}{9})=4^{199}(4+\frac{1}{9})$, thus, $T_{200}=4^{200}+\frac{4^{199}}{9}-\frac{601}{9}$.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I have edited my post. Could you please suggest how I can formulate such a grouping (quickly) if the question is tweaked a bit (as now the edited question contains)?

Comment: You can assume $T_n+an+b=3(T_{n-1}+a(n-1)+b)$, and solve the coefficients $a$ and $b$ by the question, then, you could solve questions like this. The most important thing is to give a formula like $c_n=kc_{n-1}$, you just need to transform the formula in question into the simple formula $c_n=kc_{n-1}$ and find what $c_n$ is.

Comment: Thank you. Also, could you please tell that how did we know that we need to transform the original sequence to a geometric sequence (and that other terms will fall in place accordingly)?

Comment: I think it's depend the type of $T_n$ and $T_{n-1}$ that the question gives, for example, if the type is $T_n$ and $k T_{n-1}$, then we could guess the formula could be transformed to $c_n=k c_{n-1}$; if the type is $T_n$ and $T_{n-1}$,  then we could guess the formula could be transformed to $c_n= c_{n-1}+m$, if the type is $T_n$ and $T_{n-1}^2$,  then we could guess the formula could be transformed to $c_n= c_{n-1}^2$. What you guess is all depend the type of the $T_n$ and $T_{n-1}$, that's my opinion, I hope my thoughts could help you, wish you best.

Comment: They sure did help me a lot. Thank you. Already upvoted.

Comment: Hey, sorry for being so late but I realised that I accepted the answer wrongly. Could you please edit your answer to include whatever you have answered in comments to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$T_n = 4T_{n-1} + n - 1$$

by substitution we have

$$\begin{align*}
T_n &= 4 T_{n-1} + n - 1 \\[1ex]
&= 4^2 T_{n-2} + (n-1) + 4 (n-2) \\[1ex]
&= 4^3 T_{n-3} + (n-1) + 4 (n-2) + 4^2 (n-3) \\[1ex]
&~\vdots \\[1ex]
&= 4^k T_{n-k} + (n-1) + 4 (n-2) + 4^2 (n-3) + \cdots + 4^{k-1} (n-k) \\[1ex]
&= 4^k T_{n-k} + \sum_{i=1}^k 4^{i-1} (n-i)
\end{align*}$$

When $k=n-1$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
T_n &= 4^{n-1}T_{n-(n-1)} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 4^{i-1} (n-i) \\[1ex]
&= 4^{n-1}T_1 + n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 4^{i-1} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \cdot 4^{i-1} \\[1ex]
&= 4^n + \frac{n(4^n-4)}{12} - \frac{4^{n+1} - 3n\cdot4^n - 4}{36} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac{4^{n+1}}{36} + 4^n - \frac n3 + 9
\end{align*}$$

and from here you can evaluate $T_{200}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn) for methods on computing the geometric sums.

Comment: Thank you. Wow! Didn't expect too see it solved this way as I tried my best to form such a series but wasn't successful. Glad to know that this option is available too.  +1. Thank you.