# Find the number of positive integers n such that $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}<10$ for any finite number of square root signs.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, square-numbers

Find the number of positive integers $n$ such that $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}<10$ for any finite number of square root signs.

I know something with squaring and repeating, but what does "finite number of square root signs" mean?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: On re-reading, I think my first interpretation (now deleted) was incorrect.  I now believe it means:  find all natural numbers $n$ such that each of $n, \sqrt n, \sqrt {n+\sqrt n}, \sqrt {n+\sqrt {n+\sqrt n}}, \cdots$ is less than $10$.  The sequence, to be clear, is $a_i$ where $a_1=n$ and $a_{i+1}=\sqrt {n+a_i}$

Comment: @lulu I don't think that the $0$-root expression would be $n$. Logically continuing it based on the recurrence would give the zeroth term as $0$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  Yes, I agree.  My sequence should begin with $a_0=0$, though the recursion, $a_{i+1}=\sqrt {n+a_i}$ was correct.  This makes $a_1=\sqrt n$ and $n$ itself does not appear in the sequence at all.

Comment: @DS I have rollback-ed your edit as 1. Hopefully your doubt has been resolved. 2. Such edits aren't appreciated. 3. Correct way is to ask the users like you already did and then wait a bit (some times it's even more than a day) to get the reply. 4. If you edit question in such a way that now the answer would require a different answer to be posted since the question is changed that much then the correct thing to do instead is to post a new question. For example: [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530051/t-n-4t-n-1-rightarrow-t-n-4n-1t-1-but-how).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the question means to ask you, as mentioned by the user ***lulu***, that: 
Find all natural numbers $n$ such that each of $\sqrt n,\sqrt{n+\sqrt n}, \sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt n}},\dots$ is less than 10. 
Which is a round-about way of asking:
Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt {n+\dots}}}<10$.

To solve it, we may use the standard operating procedure:
$$\text{Let }\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt {n+\dots}}}=x$$
$$\Rightarrow\sqrt{n+x}=x$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2-x-n=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}$$
And we are given that $x<10$. So:
$$\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}<10$$
$$\pm\sqrt{1+4n}<19$$
$$1+4n<361$$
$$n<90$$

But for an infinite sequence would $n=90$ not be less than $10$. Thus, for a finite sequence $n=90$ shouldn't be a problem.
Had we got something like $n<89.92$ then we would have concluded that max value $n$ can assume is $89$.

Thus, for your case, $n$ can be any value from $1$ to $90$.

Comment: that matches with the answer scheme, but why should we consider only 90, maybe 91 would work too...

Comment: @DS no it wont. First lets check this way: $\sqrt {91+\sqrt {91}}=10.027$ which does not satisfies the condition. Second, see we are getting a limit of 90 at infinity so we can say 90 will work for finite. But 91 is waaayyy far off from 90 and we can't make that jump. Even if $n$ was real, still we'd get $n\in[0,90]$ for finite root sign as even 90.00000000001 would not satisfy the condition, say for, 1,000,000,000,000 number of square roots. Still considering $n$ to be real, if we had got 6.625 as answer then too only 6.625 would satisfying condition even for a VERY large number (not 6.626).

Comment: For $n=90.001$ it is enough to have 5 roots to obtain result more than 10.

Comment: thanks @InanimateBeing

Comment: @DS glad I was helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

As the number of square roots goes from $1$ to $\infty$, the nested radical will increase *monotonically* from $\sqrt n$ to a limit of [$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4n}}2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115501/357390). This means

- if a choice of $n$ produces a limit greater than $10$, it is inadmissible since some finite number of square roots will also produce a result greater than $10$
- if a choice of $n$ produces a limit less than $10$, it is admissible; all finite nested radicals of its form will produce lesser results

Now
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4n}}2<10\implies n<90$$
This is the tighter bound on $n$, since $\sqrt n<10\implies n<100$. $n=90$ is also admissible though since we deal with a *finite* number of square roots, not the limit. There are thus $90$ admissible integers.

Comment: that matches with the answer scheme, but why should we consider only 90, maybe 91 would work too...

Comment: @DS $\sqrt{91+\sqrt{91}}>10$.